# .wxs only two file not getting deleted on uninstall

Tags: wix3.5, wix3

I am using wix installer for msi.
i am using default UI

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
```

There are somany dll i am using for msi package. on installation all dll will be installed at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp

while on uninstall all dll uninstalled or deleted except two dll

1. libssl-1_1.dll
2. libcrypto-1_1.dll

I found that identifier '-' is making problem on uninstalling and not getting deleted.

I tried custom action like this for deleting that folder itself, but it didn't work.

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>  
        <Directory Id="ALLUSERSPROFILE" SourceName="All Users" />
        <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' SourceName="program files">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" >
               <Component Id="First.dll" Guid="GUID">
                        <File Id="first.dll" Name="first.dll" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" Source="$(var.PATH)\first.dll" />
               </Component>
               ....... All dll component place like above ......
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
</Directory>

<Property Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyProj\MyApp" Type="raw" Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
    </Property>

    <DirectoryRef Id='INSTALLDIR'>
        <Component Id="UninstallFolder" Guid="*">
            <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLDIR"/>
            <util:RemoveFolderEx Property="INSTALLDIR" On="uninstall"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLDIR" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyProj\MyApp" Name="path" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]MyApp   " KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: You are certain that both `libssl-1_1.dll` and `libcrypto-1_1.dll` are correctly included in your component list?

Comment: Yes it included correctly

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to delete it manually and it should remove itself on an uninstall. The exceptions I can think of is if the Dlls were moved/modifed. It might help showing the component list of those Dlls here.